# Family membership online signup

Tags: wordpress

Just so I'm clear on this. There is no way to create a family membership online signup form that allows both partners to become members by signing up with one form when running on Wordpress. in other words, places for both members to enter names, phone # and emails. This seems like such a basic requirement and I see it has been kicked around since 2013, with no real resolution. I have seen that migrating to Drupal and using a third party Webform it is possible, but that is probably not an option for us. I just need clarification before going in search of another solution, in case I'm missing something.
Thanks, Ray

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) 2 parts here:

1. What does 'family membership' mean in your context?
2. How to sign-up for it.

For 1) you can have the membership attached to the 'primary' partner and use inherited memberships and relationships to apply it to the other partner (and kids).  [One org I worked with wanted a symmetric arrangement so either partner could renew so they used households to hold the membership.]

For 2), the core membership sign-up pages won't let you add two lots of contact details to create the membership and relationships etc. As you note, webform is a common option for doing this on Drupal.

On WP, you could have used Caldera Forms but that is being retired and the Ninja Forms replacement is not yet released. (See other posts for more details of that)

Alternatively, you could use the [Contact Form 7 CiviCRM](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-civicrm-integration/) integration to create your form on WP and pass the data through to the [Form Processor](https://civicrm.org/extensions/form-processor) extension to create the contacts and membership. However, I don't think you can take payments this way.

Eventually you should be able to create this with [Form Builder](https://civicrm.org/form-builder), but not yet.

Comment: Aidan thanks for the response. I have pretty much concluded the same things you mentioned. All we need in addition to individual memberships, which work well, is the ability to have an online form where someone chooses a family membership, they are presented with a form where they can enter the two primary members (Husband & wife) click join and the system creates both members that are associated with the membership then takes them to the payment processor.  I just found out the guy that has wrote and maintained Webforms is about to make a career change and may stop development of it.

Comment: You could do it as a 2-stage process:  use the normal membership signup forms to select and pay for a 'family' membership, then send a link to a form for them to provide details of the other member.

Comment: Aidan that might be an option, thanks.